# Tera Term logged files are missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, terminal

I've logged 3 serial devices for hours with Tera Term and the output files somehow disappeared. When I try to log again, it shows the missing files in the file dialog (anchor_log_1.csv, anchor_log_2.csv, anchor_log_3.csv). When I try to access this folder via explorer, I can't see the files. Also, I can't open or copy the files from the file dialog of Tera Term. It simply says those files do not exist. Have anyone came across this kind of error using Tera Term?

Here is the Tera Term log file dialog

[image: Tera Term log file dialog]

Here is the folder when I browse with explorer

[image: the folder when I browse with explorer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to relog my data by going to `Setup` > `Additional settings` > `Log` and turn on `Auto start logging`. Make sure to save your settings, then do `File` > `Replay log`.

An easier way would be to replay log, select all, copy and paste but my dataset was too large. I also made sure to log my files in a different directory in case that was part of the problem.